# How to manage base href with angular/localize

Tags: angular, angular-localize

I implemented internationalization in my angular project taking advantage of `angular/localize` module.
Now I have one bundle per language. If I launch the angular build I have two folders: `en` and `it`.

If I put in the browser the relative paths: `http://localhost:4200/en` or `http://localhost:4200/it` all works fine, but if I put `http://localhost:4200` in my browser I got an error. This route doesn't exist and it's true. Is there a way to do it? Is there a possibility to avoid error on origin and get a redirect to correct route?

Is there a way, with angular, based on the browser language to redirect the origin `http://localhost:4200` to the correct url?

Example: The default language is English, but if my browser language is setted to italian, and italian language is available in my internationalization, I have to redirect to italian app.

Answer (score 0):

Use `const userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/language. Then use var `userLang` to set the right url.